# counting issue on scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a probem using scrapy, I want to crawl the number of episodes from one serie but my counter seem not to increment properly, here is my code

```
def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
    count = 0
    for sel in response.xpath('//div[@id="content"]'):
        item = CouchtunerItem()
        item['number_of_episodes'] = sel.xpath('span[@class="catDivTest"]/a/text()').extract()
        count += 1
        item['number_of_episodes'] = count
        yield item
```

But my count give me `1` at every loop.

Comment: If it gives you 1 always then `response.xpath('//div[@id="content"]')` returns a single element, also `enumerate` would do the counting for you

Comment: Why do you have `number_of_episodes` twice? Could you give a more concrete example? I think what you mean is `item['number_of_episodes'] = len(sel.xpath('...'))` here. Your code doesn't make much sense right now.

Comment: Try to do `response.xpath("")` in the parent node of the @id=content. Have in mind that html attribute id generally has not a duplicated value in the same DOM. (If it is written following w3c) so **it's rare you receive a count of more than one** using that code.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice that the     response.xpath('//div[@id="content"]')                                                     was returning a single element. Thanks.